# Is there a diffeomorphism $f$ such that $V(B) < V(f(B)) <V(B)+V(B)^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Simple to understand calculus question that involved change of variable theorem in integration.

Suppose $B$ is some **open** ball in $\mathbb R^n$, and $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is a diffeomorphism. Meaning $f$ is bijective and continuous and the differential of $f$ is also continuous.

Let $V(B)$ be the volume of the ball $B$.

Show there is no such diffeomorphism $f$ such that $V(B) < V(f(B)) <V(B)+V(B)^2$ for any open ball $B$.

I know that the idea of the proof is to consider a ball with a very very very small radius $\epsilon$. If we can show that for a ball with a very small radius there is no such diffeomorphism, then we found a ball where $V(B) < V(f(B)) <V(B)+V(B)^2$ and we're done.

But how can i show theres no such $f$ for a small ball?

Comment: It would seem that such a diffeomorphism has its differential of constant determinant equal to one. But then the change of variable formula tells you that for any measurable set $A$, in particular for any ball $B$, the measure of $f(A)$ is equal to that of $A$, which contradicts the assumption $V(B)<V(f(B))$ for open balls.

Comment: Why is the jacobian $1$?

Comment: Because for any $x\in\Bbb R^n$, you should have $$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{V(f(B(x,r)))}{V(B(x,r))}=|d_xf|$$ and your hypothesis forces this limit to be one everywhere.